# Why I can't get an ID instead of a row number in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm working in a project that uses jqGrid, here is my code:

```
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "/Roles/ObtenerAccionesGrid/",
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames: ['id', 'Acción', 'Tipo de Acción', 'Función'],
            colModel: [
              { name: 'iIdAccion', index: 'iIdAccion', width: 50, align: 'left', key:true },
              { name: 'sDescripcionAccion', index: 'sDescripcionAccion', width: 150, align: 'left' },
              { name: 'sTipoAccion', index: 'sTipoAccion', width: 150, align: 'left', sortable: false },
              { name: 'sDescripcionFuncion', index: 'sDescripcionFuncion', width: 80, align: 'left' }],
            height: 400,
            rowNum: 1000,
            mtype: 'GET',
            pager: $("#pager"),
            sortname: 'Funcion',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            pgbuttons: false,
            pginput: false,
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/content/cupertino/images',
            caption: 'Funciones',
            grouping: true,
            multiselect: true,
            groupingView: { groupField: ['sDescripcionFuncion'], groupColumnShow: [false], groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} Accion(es)</b>'] },
            width: 1190,
            loadComplete: function () {
                var iIdPerfil = document.getElementById("iIdPerfil").attributes.value;
                $.getJSON("/Roles/ObtenerAccionesPerfil" + "/" + iIdPerfil.value, function (acciones) {
                    $.each(acciones, function (key, acciones) {
                        $("#list").jqGrid('setSelection', acciones.iIdAccion);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

When I run the project I get the following response:

[image: jqGrid problem demonstrations]

Until here everything is ok, but when I try to know the Id of rows selected with the folowing code (see console), I always get the row number:

`$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');`

[image: jqGrid problem demonstration 2]

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking -- You have a problem with the format that it gives you. What of it? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I just want to get the id of the selected rows, but I'm always getting the rows number with the code shown

Comment: Use selrow as a key instead of selarrrow. $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');